# Bootstrap table showing a grey horizontal scroll bar while printing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, printing

I am trying to print a webpage with bootstrap tables. But when I press command/ctrl + P, a horizontal scroll bar appears. I am not getting where it is coming from.

I can see some space below the table (within the blue shed). That is where the scroll bar appears.

[image: Developer Tools > Inspect div]

After pressing command/ctrl + P, I get something like this.

[image: Print preview]

How can I get rid of this scroll bar?

It is a quite straightforward example. Still, here is the code.

```css
@page {
  size: auto;
  margin: 7mm;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i&amp;display=swap">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@bootstrapstudio/bootstrap-better-nav/dist/bootstrap-better-nav.min.css">

<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="font-weight-bold f14" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">Total Paid
            </td>
            <td>$ 5,023.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="font-weight-bold f14" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">Invoice Date
            </td>
            <td class="f14" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">11-11-2022</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="font-weight-bold f14" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">Invoice #</td>
            <td class="f14" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;">11</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML doesn't show a container. Bootstrap requires this to offset the margins on the rows and columns. Does your page have one? Also, inline styles are awful, especially when Bootstrap already provides bordered tables.

Comment: Tried adding .container. Did not work. Anyway, thanks for your response and edits.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is a scrollbar. So I tried to hide it and it worked. To get rid of the scroll bar from the table add this CSS to that table.

```
element.style {
    overflow-x: visible;
}
```

And it should go away

Comment: You're hiding a symptom of a layout issue with that and possibly cutting off content. It's not a solution, in my opinion.